# ASP.NET Core API Service authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm developing an app that requires a fairly complex authentication scenario.

The app it self is an Angular 7 app with ASP.NET Core 2.2 backend. I have implemented Azure Active directory authentication for the app and backend services, which works well.

I also have a requirement for a few of the web API methods to be invoked by sensors (raspberry pi running Windows IoT Core and a UWP App). I can't think of an approach at the moment and looking for recommendations? Is it possible to mix and match authentication mechanisms in ASP.NET core, and say add authentication based on Certificate or something similar?

Comment: Yes, is possible, we have an Angular 6 App able to do this, it took a while to enable this capability because you need to configure many things and implement others. We use Cookie Authentication and authenticate users 'manually' by using HttpContext.SignInAsync, to capture the authentication state we applied a route constraint to check if the requester is authenticated, and if not, decide what to do, like redirect to the IdP or authenticate the request using a different method (header, api-key). Web API Controllers are just decorated with the Authorize attribute.

Comment: Not sure about your requirement , do you have any other client to access your api application which protected by AAD ? Or do you want to combine local user login with AAD login in your angular app ?

Comment: @Nan Yu The angular application is used by normal human users primarily, however there are a couple of webapi methods that are invoked by external sensors - in this case Raspberry pi devices that are sitting on trucks sending gps locations. I need these methods to be protected by other mechanism than AzureAD tokens, as managing these would be tricky, as they expire and there is no human interaction with raspberry pi

Comment: Then try to not use [Authorize] attribute on actions which should not protected by AAD , write your custom authentication logic in them .